# C++ Hash table to JSON

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, hash

## Context:

I have a C++ Hashtable(STL map):

The map uses integer as keys and objects as content.

I want to transfer this allocated data structure to a JSON file and parse it with a C# script(unity) so I can recreate the hashtable inside C#.

## Problem:

I created a JSON file like so:

```
      {
         "123": {obj},
         "145": {obj},
         "124": {obj}
      }
```

How can I parse this into a C# hash table?

Is there a more effective way to recreate the hash-table? (Minimizing the computing done by C# script)

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Seems like you should remove the `c++` tag from this question, as you just want to know how to parse `JSON` into C#.

Comment: Why is performance an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple example that reads in a dictionary along with some other items. It is more efficient than the build in microsoft one, but is still slow compared to go and other languages.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(args[0]);

        Message sdata = new Message();

        sdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(json);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Test
{
    public int a;
    public float b;
    public string c;
    public int [] d;
    public Dictionary<string,int> e;
}

[Serializable]
public class Message
{
    public String text;
    public Test[] data;
}
```

Json that it reads in

{

```
  "text": "lel",
  "data": [{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2.2,
    "c": "a03e714b-3030-420c-b62f-383128c1af0a",
    "d": [1,2,3],
    "e": { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }
  }, {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2.2,
    "c": "a03e714b-3030-420c-b62f-383128c1af0a",
    "d": [1,2,3],
    "e": { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }
}]
}
```

Comment: The OP is using Unity which has it's own built in [JsonUtilty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html), you only need to make minor changes to make the code work with Unity's vesion